# Removing flicker in fisheye cameras due to auto exposure

Tags: opencv, image-processing, camera, computer-vision, autoexposurecompensation

I am working on surround view monitoring system where the driver of the vehicle gets
360 view of the vehicle surroundings.

When there is a considerable change in the amount of light entering the 
camera, there is a rapid change in auto-exposure frame to frame and the camera produces 
a flicker. For example when the camera is facing Sun and moving away from Sun
auto-exposure changes rapidly and flickering occurs.

I have tried setting a constant exposure value. Though the flickering effect
is avoided, setting a constant exposure value produces over-saturation
or under-saturation at different lighting conditions and hence it is not a 
practical solution.

Any links to literature or any kind of sources would be much appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: I'm voting to close this question since it is not directly programming related. This should be asked here: https://photo.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: You can maybe try a smoother function for changing the exposure (not [mathematical smooth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smoothness), I mean a function with a more relaxed slope). It seems that the default function is too sharp (thus overshoots and flickers) and the constant function you have tried is, well, constant (too smooth).

Comment: Thank you for the response. The function for auto exposure is implemented in the camera ISP and I don't think it can be tweaked. Setting exposure value to a constant was done by setting some camera registers as mentioned in the camera data sheet.

Answer (score 0):

There could some options which restrict the algorithm to react quickly based on scene change, you can try reducing that option. Here it looks like as soon as the scene is changing (like facing the sun and away from the sun) reacts very quickly.